# Using regular expressions to find all anagrams of string present in another string

Tags: java, regex

I want to search for all anagrams of a string present in another and then output the count.I know the standard method to do it and i have already done it in O(m*n)  time complexity where m and n are length of the two strings but i was wondering how can we do that using regular expression.Is there a way to do so?By what i tried i didn't get a correct output in cases like this: pattern-aaba str-aabaabaa.Its output should have been 4 but by what i tried i got 2.Here is the most basic method i tried:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[aaba]{4}");
Matcher m=p.matcher("aabaabaa");
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
int count=0;
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group(0));
}
System.out.println(matches+" "+matches.size());
```

Thank you for help in advance :)

Comment: Yes,i'm looking for overlapping matches but i want to get 4 aaba permutation matches here

Comment: 4..as there are 4 permutation of aaba in the bigger string

Comment: You can use your pattern to filter (by character and length) useless positions in a string, but after you need to test if each match has all the letters (count them). But there's no way to find permutations with regex only.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte but [aaba]{4} already generates all the permutation ..i just need to find if all of those exist in the bigger string but i can't figure out how to search for it if it contains overlapping substrings

Comment: @ani Casimir has a point: Your regex also produces "aaaa", "bbbb", "aabb" and so on (i.e. all permutations, but then some non-permutations). Furthermore, you pointed out yourself that regexes do not work with overlapping matches. I don't think they are the rigth tool for the job.

Comment: @ani: about overlapping results, it can be done using a lookahead and a capture group: `(?=([aaba]{4}))`. Malte Hartwig has well explained what I means, indeed `[aaba]{4}` is the same than `[ab]{4}` and match any four characters length combination of `a` and `b`, not only the permutations of `aaba`. That's why you have to count the letters for each match result.

Comment: I would just [find all the permutations](http://javarevisited.blogspot.be/2015/08/how-to-find-all-permutations-of-string-java-example.html) of the search string, put those anagrams into an array, remove the duplicates from it, then search for each anagram.

Comment: `[aaba]` does not do what you think.  It is identical to `[ab]`.  There are many resources which explain how regular expressions work;  since you’re using Java, the [Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is a good place to start.